# How to make Rcpp code efficient with multiple for loops?

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to implement following Rcpp code by calling from R. The computing time is extremely slow. There are lots of for loops involved.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat qpart(
      const int& n,
      const int& p,
      const int& m,
      arma::vec& G,
      arma::vec& ftime,
      arma::vec& cause,
      arma::mat& covs,
      arma::mat& S1byS0hat,
      arma::vec& S0hat,
      arma::vec& expz){

      arma::mat q(n,p);
      q.zeros();
      for(int u=0;u<n;++u){
         arma::mat q1(1,p);
         q1.zeros();
         for(int iprime=0;iprime<n;++iprime){
            for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
               if(cause(iprime)==1 & cause(i)>1 & (ftime(i) < ftime(u)) & (ftime(u) <= ftime(iprime))){
                   q1 += (covs.row(i) - S1byS0hat.row(iprime))*G(iprime)/G(i)*expz(i)/S0hat(iprime);
               }
             }
         }
         q.row(u) = q1/(m*m);
      }
return q;
}
```

Following is an example in R.

```
#### In R ########
n = 2000
m = 500
p=3
G = runif(n)
ftime = runif(n,0.01,5)
cause = c(rep(0,600),rep(1,1000),rep(2,400))
covs = matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p)
S1byS0hat = matrix(rnorm(n*p),p,n)
S0hat = rnorm(n)
expz = rnorm(n)

system.time( qpart(n,p,m,G,ftime,cause,covs,t(S1byS0hat),S0hat,expz))
user  system elapsed 
   21.5     0.0    21.5
```

As we can see, the computing time is very high.

Same code implemented in R and the computing time is very high.

```
q = matrix(0,n,p)
for(u in 1 : n){
    q1 <- matrix(0,p,1)
  for(iprime in 1 : n){
    for(i in 1 : n){
      if(cause[iprime]==1 & cause[i]>1 & (time[i]<time[u]) & (time[u] <= time[iprime])){
          q1 = q1 + (covs[i,] - S1byS0hat[,iprime])*G[iprime]/G[i]*expz[i]/S0hat[iprime]
      }
    }

  }
    q[u,] = q1/(m*m)
}
```

Following is the formula that I am trying to implement.
[image]

Comment: your `if` statement is wrong. In C++ the `&` is a bitwise AND. You need `&&` for a logical AND. Otherwise, the `if` statement will essentially always evaluate to TRUE and run your expensive calculation. The result will be wrong and the calculation slower than it needs to be.

Comment: @ Allan Cameron Actually I wrote the same code in R and results from R and using Rcpp produced exactly same result. Okay, I will try with &&.

Comment: @ Allan Cameron Yes with that change the computing time comes down to 10.3 secs. Do you see any further improvements?

Comment: @ Allan Cameron Do you think it would be better just to stick with R and try to optimize in R?

Comment: what is it that you're calculating? When you set n = 2000 and doing a triple nested loop, you are executing 2000 x 2000 x 2000, or 8 **billion** calculations. Having it run in 10s means you are getting almost a billion calculations per second in Rcpp. That's not slow, it's fast. It's _going_ to take a long time unless there is a better algorithm that does what you're trying to achieve. Unless you can tell us that, you're going to struggle to get it much better.

Comment: @AllanCameron Sure, I can tell you what I am doing. Would you like to see the formula? I have also added R code that does the same thing but it takes very long. I was wondering, if we could do some vectorization in R.

Comment: you need to realise that "under the hood" R's vectorisation is done with loops in C++ and Fortran. It works well because it uses efficient algorithms. Let us know what you're doing and post the formula - that will help to find optimisations.

Comment: @ Allan Cameron Please see the formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206645/discussion-between-hello-and-allan-cameron).

Comment: You should order more efficiently the if statements.

Comment: @F.Prive Could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some conditions depends only on `u` and `iprime` so you can check them much before.
You can also precompute some stuff. This gives:

```
arma::mat qpart2(
    double m,
    arma::vec& ftime,
    arma::vec& cause,
    arma::mat& covs,
    arma::mat& S1byS0hat,
    arma::vec& G_div_S0hat,
    arma::vec& expz_div_G){

  double m2 = m * m;

  int n = covs.n_rows;
  int p = covs.n_cols;

  arma::mat q(n, p, arma::fill::zeros);

  for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
    double ftime_u = ftime(u);
    for (int iprime = 0; iprime < n; iprime++) {
      if (cause(iprime) == 1 && ftime_u <= ftime(iprime)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          if (cause(i) > 1 && ftime(i) < ftime_u) {
            double coef = G_div_S0hat(iprime) * expz_div_G(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
              q(u, j) += (covs(i, j) - S1byS0hat(iprime, j)) * coef;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)  q(u, j) /= m2;
  }

  return q;
}
```

Using `qpart2(m, ftime, cause, covs, t(S1byS0hat), G / S0hat, expz / G)` takes **3.7 sec** (vs **32 sec** for your code).

**

Small remarks:

- Is there a reason why you are using arma structures instead of Rcpp ones?
- You should access matrices by columns, not by rows, it should be a bit faster because they are stored column-wise.

Comment: Prive Wow. That's a big improvement. You are saying that if we use Rcpp structure then we can improve further. There is no reason for me to use arma structure. I was just more familiar with it.

Comment: No, it won't improve speed, but it would be much simpler, and remove one dependency.

Comment: Would it be possible to use vector through out Rcpp to make it even more efficient. I am asking because the similar code written in C (not by me) is way faster than above.